# How can I execute shell script from a jar file

Tags: java, shell, jar, root

I am using shell commands inside java. When I run the project in netbeans it is working well. But when I run the jar file of the project through the command line it is giving this error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Can you tell if there is a way to run shell commands from jar file?

Comment: What is the code you tried?

Comment: rabbitmqctl list_queues      is the command which i want to execute and to get the working queue list. I run the jar file as root.

Comment: Post your code which executes this command.

Comment: String[] cmd = {"rabbitmqctl list_queues"};
Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));

Comment: try the put the command and its argument into separate string, like this: String[] cmd = {"rabbitmqctl", "list_queues"};

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options:

1. You can use RunTime class. `Runtime getRuntime() exec(String command)` 
   Look [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for more information.
2. You can use ProcessBuilder.  `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();` Look into [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more information.
3. You can use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) API to execute Linux/Unix commands from your local machine to any remote system. You can create a shell script in your java code ( if you are running multiple shell commands) and then set up a jsch connection to the remote server. With the jsch connection, you can copy the shell script to remote server and run the entire shell script. I find this 3rd option very useful.